# Make a DLL out of a Windows Forms Project

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a solution with 2 projects in it. One of the projects can only be run from the other. I want to convert it to DLL, so that end-users cannot directly run it (as it is, they get 2 executables). Is there any straightforward way to do this, without having to copy the entire project?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, go to the Project Properties, Application tab and change the Output Type.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd rather play with the .csproj xml, you want to change the OutputType from `WinExe` (or `Exe`) to `Library`, it should be found near the top of the file:

```
<Project ...>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGUID>{YOURGUID-ABCD-0123-4567-0123456789AB}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you don't want the second executable to be run by the user (only by your program) then make a check in the program (that shouldn't be executed by the user) for an argument or something like that to match, to know that your main program started it.

Comment: that is an excellent solution to prevent the user from 'accidentally' running the application but is not the solution for the issue at hand. He has a Library (dll) which is currently (incorrectly) an executable and he wishes to convert.